# Добавить значения в массив php

Tags: php, json

Здесь будет ошибка:

```
    $from = $_POST['from'];
            $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM puzzles LIMIT $from,10");

            while(($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))!=false){
                $res = array();
                for($i = 0; $i <10; $i++) {
                    array_push($res, row[i]['description'], row[i]['id']);
                }
}
```

Как добавить в массив элементы в виде [[row[i]['description'], row[i]['id']],[row[i]['description'], [и так далее]] ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM puzzles LIMIT $from,10");
    while(($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))!=false){
        $res = array(); # зачем в цикле каждый раз определять масив?
        for($i = 0; $i <10; $i++) { # и еще одну выборку гонять 10 раз
            # у тебя $row масив на выходе каждый раз обнавляеться (while) с именами столбцов в таблице
            # row['description'], row['id']... поэтому ты добавляешь непонятно что (+ нету $)
             array_push($res, row[i]['description'], row[i]['id']);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

PHP в отличии от JAVA не строгий язык, поэтому проблем с добавлением в массив нет.

```
    <?
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM puzzles LIMIT $from,10");
    $res = array();
$i=0;
    while(($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))){
             $res[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
             $res[$i]['description'] = $row['description'];
$i++;
    }
    ?>
```